# Two azure function pipeline in CD deploy to one application service not working

Tags: c#, azure, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

I am trying to deploy two azure functions project to one function app.
I use two CD pipelines for two projects, which is one pipeline for one project.

[image]

function1 is from project 1 from pipeline1 and function2 is from project 2 from piepline2.
The problem is when function2 is released, function1 doesn't work.
When function1 is released, function2 doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This is the existing behavior and there is an existing [**`Github issue`**](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/1106) referencing the same.

As per the [`GuideLines`](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/wiki/Deploying-Function-Apps-vs-individual-Functions),

> the unit of deployment should be the Function App, and not individual
>   functions.